# Gas minimal limit on private blockchain

Tags: gas-limit, genesis, poa

I'm trying to set a PoA private Blockchain. I have a problem with the gas limit : Actually, as there's not enough transactions, the gas limit is decreasing continuously . Is there any way I can set in the genesis file a minimal limit the gas shouldn't go below?

Thank's in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the genesis file there is a `gasLimit` field that is used to set the intial gas level but like you're seeing this will move up or down with every block. These values are only applicable to the genesis block.

But you should be able to use the `--targetgaslimit` flag to set a value that the gas limit will move towards.

Comment: Thks for the reply, I will test it.
If I set the same value in the genesis gasLimit field and in each sealer/miner using --targetgaslimit, does it mean that the gas limit will stay always the same? at this value? even if there's no transaction for a while?

Comment: You should only need to set that `--targetgaslimit` once. I'm unsure, I'd need to test it, but that is what I would expect.